# Configuring Multilayer switch IPV6 error : Overlapping

Tags: networking

%Vlan1: Error: 2001:DB8:ABCD:A::/64 is overlapping with 2000::/6
while giving ipv6 address to the multilayer switch I am getting the following error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.